# DataEvent Parameter {primaryKeys} is invalid

Tags: marketing-cloud

Once I send the dataevents (Put) request to ET Journey Builder getting the below exception.

> Endpoint:

Endpoint=https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataevents/Externalkey
  (ex:123)/rows/sample@exacttaget.com?access_token=yq3

```
Exception:
          OC:{

               "message":"Parameter {primaryKeys} is invalid.",
               "errorcode":10005,
               "documentation":""
              }
```

Please help on this.

Comment: If you could post the code it would help to see what might be going on.

Comment: Hi Rob Weis, thank you for your response. please see the code below.  service request {
    "values": {
        "LastName": "kittu",
        "LastLogin": "2015-06-9T15:32:00Z",
        "IsActive": true,
        "FollowerCount": "2",
        "FirstName": "suman"
    }
}   End point: ttps://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataevents/123/rows/email:sample@exacttaget.com?access_token=yq3    Exception: {"message":"Primary key 'Email' does not exist.","errorcode":10000,"documentation":""}

Comment: Hi Rob weis, i am following the below link for implement this requirment                                  https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/hub/data-events/putDataExtensionRowByKey.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your JSON payload should be OK. The error is stating that the primary does not exist.

This could be due to the client ID/client secret you are using to make the API call is not connected to the account that has the data extension you are trying to write to.

The only other reason would be that you are possibly using the data extension name instead of the Primary Key (in the app this is called the External Key under the Properties tab).

If you are sure you have the correct id/secret from the account, try removing any spaces from the external key in the app/UI and retry the call.

Comment: It also looks like you have email: lowercase in the call (example has the E capitalized) and have you verified that the data extension has an EmailAdress field marked 'primary key?' For the email based call to work you have to have EmailAddress marked as primary key and already in the DE. If you want to use another key you can use this: https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/hub/data-events/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.html

Comment: HI Rob Weis,  even i change the email lowecase to upppercase still same problem. Endpoint=https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataevents/key:0AEFDACDAB3/rows/Email:rash@tft.com?access_token=mp7kb5r9. EmaiAddres already marked as a primarykey in DE.

Comment: Does the email address you are using on the call already exist in the DE?